# WebDav/Kerberos on Windows issue - cannot authenticate to a website from a trusted domain in another forest

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, webdav, kerberos

I found a Microsoft support article that describes the exact scenario except the article addresses Server 2003 instead of Server 2008R2:  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=830576 .

The resolution in the article is to establish a two way trust between forests so the trusting domain can access the Kerberos key server in the trusted domain.  That is unfortunately not a possibility in this network.

I'm hoping there is some other way to get Kerberos happening between these two domains even though the trust is only one direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link says it straight out: you need a two way trust. No other option. This is how we do it with tens of subdomains.